# How can I prevent specific classes from being updated/deleted in SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, session, event-handling, sqlalchemy

Let's say I have classes Dog(), Walrus(), Boot().
I want to make it so you cannot update Walrus objects ever although you can delete them and you can never delete Boot objects.
So if do:

```
dog1 = Dog("DogName")
walrus1 = Walrus("WalrusName")
boot1 = Boot("BootName")
session.add(dog1)
session.add(walrus1)
session.add(boot1)
session.flush()
transaction.commit()
dog1.name = "Fluffy"
walrus1.name = "Josh"
boot1.name = "Pogo"
session.flush()
transaction.commit()
```

It would throw an exception on changing the walrus name but allow the others to be changed.
If I tried to delete boot1 it would throw an exception.

I've taken a couple stabs at event listeners but both ways I've approached don't get me all the way there:

```
#One possibility
#I don't know how to tell that it's just an update though
#The is_modified seems to take inserts as well

@event.listens_for(Session, 'before_flush')
def listener(thissession, flush_context, instances):
    for obj in thissession:
        if isinstance(obj, Walrus):
            if thissession.is_modified(obj, include_collections=False):
                thissession.expunge(obj)


#Possiblity two
#It says before_update but it seems to take in inserts as well
#Also documentation says it's not completely reliable to capture all statements
#where an update will occur
@event.listens_for(Walrus, 'before_update', raw=True)
def pleasework(mapper, connection, target):
    print "\n\nInstance %s being updated\n\n" % target
    object_session(target).expunge(target)
```

EDIT 1:

```
@event.listens_for(Walrus, 'before_update', raw=True)
def prevent_walrus_update(mapper, connection, target):
    print "\n\nInstance %s being updated\n\n" % target
    if target not None:
        raise

@event.listens_for(Boot, 'before_delete', raw=True)
def prevent_boot_delete(mapper, connection, target):
    print "\n\nInstance %s being deleted\n\n" % target
    if target not None:
        raise
```

I've got this to work where it won't allow me to make updates to Walrus or deletions to Boot, but any hint at an attempt to will crash with an AttributeError that I don't seem to have any ability to catch. For example if I run Walrus1.name = "Josh" and then any query at al, even a get, an AttributeError will crash the application. I'm further along than I was, but still rather inconvenienced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first solution you posted looks like it should work, if you just change the loop to read:

```
for obj in thissession.dirty:
```

You can use the same `before_flush` event to prevent deletion of Boot objects by looping through `thissession.deleted`.